# PHP OOP singleton doesn't return object

Tags: php, oop, singleton

Weird trouble. I've used singleton multiple times but this particular case just doesn't want to work. Dump says that instance is null.

```
define('ROOT', "/");
define('INC', 'includes/');
define('CLS', 'classes/');

require_once(CLS.'Core/Core.class.php');

$core = Core::getInstance();

var_dump($core->instance);

$core->settings(INC.'config.php');
$core->go();
```

Core class

```
class Core
{
    static $instance;

    public $db;
    public $created = false;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->created = true;
    }   

    static function getInstance()
    {       
        if(!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new Core();
        } else {
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }

    public function settings($path = null)
    {
        ...
    }
    public function go()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Error code

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function settings() on a non-object in path
```

It's possibly some stupid typo, but I don't have any errors in my editor. Thanks for the fast responses as always.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to always return the singleton object from the singleton method, here you are not because you have an `else` statement, so the first invocation of `getInstance` will not return anything:

```
static function getInstance()
{       
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new Core();
    } else {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Your singleton method should look like this:

```
static function getInstance()
{       
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new Core();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Also, having an instance variable denoting whether an object was created is pretty much useless, because you can just compare `if(self::$instance !== NULL)` and you're good to go.

Comment: +1 Also, I think that the `$this->created` bit (in the OP) is kind of useless, because technically `(self::$instance !== null)` and `$this->created == true` are equivalent.

Comment: I know now - but I didn't realise that I had this error. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

getInstance should *always* return a value -- needs to change like this:

```
static function getInstance()
{       
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new Core();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to needing to change your getInstance() method to:

```
static function getInstance() {       
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new Core();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

...you're also trying to dereference $instance from the instance itself in the following call:

```
var_dump($core->instance);
```

You should either be checking:

```
var_dump($core);
```

or

```
var_dump(Core::$instance);
```

...which, after the $core = Core::getInstance() call, should be the same object.